# AMD Catalyst, Ubuntu 14.04, mis-identification, underscan, and other woes

Tags: display, amd-graphics

I have an Ubuntu 14.04, AMD A8 APU based hardware, and Catalyst CC (14.10?) installed. The screen is a JVC 40" HD LED LCD connected via HDMI.

The issues are:

1. Catalyst thinks the display is a projector. **Settings > Display** says it's a 32" DTV.
2. The display underscans, leaving a large black border.
3. The LCD TV has no over/under scan adjustment control, and the scaling option usually available in Catalyst is also missing. I suspect this is due to Catalyst thinking there's a projector hanging off the HDMI port.
4. **Catalyst will not save the refresh rate, always coming up at 30hertz after a reboot. This causes screen flicker. The rate needs to be 50hertz or more, which I can set for the session, but as stated is lost on a reboot.**

I suspect these problems are all related to the mis-identification of the LED LCD screen as a projector.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The following is a kludge, not a solution:
After much stuffing about and scouring the web I continued to hit brickwalls. Some suggested using aticonfig. It had no effect in my case. I was using the xfce desktop.

Out of frustration I installed Cinnamon. On booting into Cinnamon the display resolved itself, going full screen with no noticeable overscan or underscan.

Oddly, in cinnamon Catalyst saves the screen refresh rate. It did not in xfce.

I have no idea why this worked, but if you're frustrated by the useless Catalyst CC, maybe try another desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I had an underscanning issue (big black borders), although all of the information about my monitor was displayed correctly. I changed the scan setting under **Catalyst Display Manager** to **DTV** and everything is fine. I am not using a digital TV, but the result is what counts.